# Avoid malicious Javascript in RSS feeds

Tags: xss

I'm implementing an RSS client where users can select feeds and have them displayed in one place.

I noticed that some RSS feeds have HTML in the description element. Does this mean that some feeds could contain potentially malicious javascript?

Is there any safe way to render the feed's HTML? Or should I always assume that it could be malicious?

Example:

```
<description>
  <script>
    window.location.href='http://fakebook.com'
  </script>
</description>
```

Comment: *"Or should I always assume that it could be malicious?"* - you should always assume that input from sources you don't control might be malicious and sanitize the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can just disable javascript. There is not really a good reason items in RSS feeds should use it.

Answer (score 1):

Capabilities depend on how the html is being shown. I don't think attacks from major feed sources would be a big concern, but they might inline ads that could be bad. The larger vector would be embedding smaller site feeds without the controls that big players have; I've seen a lot of "hand-built" RSS, and I cringe at what could make it through a pipeline of the naive.

In term of displaying it, you can sanitize it client-side with a lib, some RegExps, or with user-agent controls, depending on the agent. In a browser, you can simply use a CSP (content security policy) to guard against script inclusion, including the pesky attribute-based events.

Embedded browsers might not support CSP options, so if that's the case, sanitize it very well. You can usually use an embedded browser's DOM to safely turn the markup into text (set innerHTML, read innerText), which removes all HTML features like links and images, but guarantees safety.